# How do you get out of the barracks view?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I opened the barracks view, assigned some gear, got back to the list of peeps, and... there's no back button, Escape does nothing.  Clicking outside the menu does nothing.  F1 does nothing.  All I can do is click on a soldier's name, and I see no way to get from that screen back to the main view, either.

What am I missing?

Comment: hmm.....   Alt- F4 ?

Comment: Wait, what? A bug in XCOM? Unpossible!

Comment: You're probably bugged.  I've seen this reported a couple of times before, with other base menus.  Your best bet is probably to exit the game and come back in :(

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but other things that you can try are ESC and right-click.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Right Clicking (assuming you're on PC). If it's not a bug keeping you from backing out, Right Clicking backs you out one step. At least, this is true on the PC version, I can't speak for other OSs.

So I noticed, and internalized (so forgot to mention), that sometimes the right click doesn't work BUT... if I left click on nothing (that is anything that isn't actually a button) and hold for a short period (long click basically) the right click often seems to work. I tend to notice this most when changing equipment around. Again if you've got a serious bug, it may just not work.

Comment: Does not work for me, I guess it's a bug.  Thanks for the suggestion, though, hopefully it will help some people!

Comment: This doesn't work if someone is speaking (ie, there is an avatar top right) then you'll have to click the actual menu buttons in order to move around the base whilst they are speaking.

Answer (score 2):

Did this happen during one of the first missions?

If it did then you can not exit the barracks until you select your sole survivor of the previous mission and promote him.

Comment: it happened to me similarly, I was in the barracks first time and it needed me to equip my first new item engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Have the exact same issue - it was after 1st missions and what I had to do was simply equip newly manufactured item/weapon to any soldier.

Answer (score -1):

If you're playing on the Steam version, it's probably the Steam Overlay interfering. I had something similar on my first ever mission. It was pretty annoying!

To fix it, just go in and out of the Steam Overlay a few times (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Comment: I am indeed using Steam.  I'll try your suggestion the next time this comes up.